# spring security, UserDetailsService, authenticationProvider, pass word encoder.. i'm lost

Tags: spring, spring-security

first, i've read/re-read (repeat 10 times), at least 6 books on spring and spring security and have googled my brains out trying to figure it all out.

after working w/ spring for 10 years, i still find that there is so much annotation-defined, injected, component, config annotation magic going on that i have 0 confidence that i understand my applications as i should. 
examples online are either xml-config, not complete, done n diff. ways, overly simplistic, using older spring, conflicting and just simply not built to handle a basic realistic use-case.

as an example, the following code is trying to handle a simple logon, authenticated to db table using an encoder for passwords.
form post includes a "client" to which one authenticates to, a persisted IP address and some url path info for deep linking post logon.
(all really basic stuff for today's single-page web apps)
i originally had this working using xml config, but javaConfig has me stuck.

i have no idea how the userDetailsService, AuthenticationManagerBuilder and PasswordEncoder interact in SecurityConfiguration. I get logon data to the service, but am not sure where or when a spring authenticationProvider is applied or if i even need one.

my User implements UserDetails and holds the required fields.
i populate those and granted authorities in my CustomUserDetailsService.
how/when/why do i need an auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()), if i check db using logon/password in my service?

my UserDetailsService seems to be executing twice now.

how does spring take the submitted password, encode it and compare to that stored in the db? 
how does it know to use the same salt as that used when the p/w was created/persisted when the user was created?

why does configureGlobal() define both auth.userDetailsService and auth.authenticationProvider when authenticationProvider() also sets the userDetailsService?

why is my brain so small that i cannot make sense of this ? :)

---

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private ClientDAO clientDAO;
@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;


public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String multipartLogon) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

    Boolean canAccess = false;
    Long clientId = null;
    String userLogon = null;
    String password = null;
    String id = null;
    String entryUrl = null;
    String ipAddress = null;
    String urlParam = null;
    String[] strParts = multipartLogon.split(":");
    try {
        userLogon = strParts[0];
        password = strParts[1];
        id = strParts[2];
        entryUrl = strParts[3];
        ipAddress = strParts[4];
        urlParam = strParts[5];
    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ioob) { }
    Client client = new Client();
    if (!"".equals(id)) {
        clientId = IdUtil.toLong(id);
        client = clientDAO.getClient(clientId);
    }

    //BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    //String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);

    //String encodedPassword = "$2a$22$6UiVlDEOv6IQWjKkLm.04uN1yZEtkepVqYQ00JxaqPCtjzwIkXDjy";


    User user = userDAO.getUserByUserLogonPassword(userLogon, password); //encodedPassword?
    user.isCredentialsNonExpired = false;
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    for (UserRole userRole : userDAO.getUserRolesForUser(user)) {
        if (userRole.getRole().getActiveStatus()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole().getRoleName()));
            user.isCredentialsNonExpired = true;
        }
    }       
    user.setAuthorities(authorities);
    user.setPassword(password); //encodedPassword?
    user.setUsername(user.getUserLogon());
    user.isAccountNonExpired = false;
    user.isAccountNonLocked = false;

    List<ClientUser> clientUsers = clientDAO.getClientUsersForUser(user);
    for (ClientUser clientUser : clientUsers) {
        if (clientUser.getClient().getClientId().equals(client.getClientId())) {
            canAccess = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    user.isEnabled = false;
    if (user.getActiveStatus() && canAccess) {
        user.isAccountNonExpired = true;
        user.isAccountNonLocked = true;
        user.isEnabled = true;

        Session session = userDAO.getSessionForUser(user);
        if (session == null) { session = new Session(); }
        session.setUser(user);
        session.setDateLogon(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        session.setClient(client);
        session.setEntryUrl(entryUrl);
        session.setUrlParam(urlParam);
        session.setIPAddress(ipAddress);
        session.setActive(true);
        userDAO.persistOrMergeSession(session);
    }
    return user;
}

}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;


@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}


@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}


@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()

        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/conv/a/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_COURT_ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/conv/u/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_COURT_ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and()

        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/conv/common/logon")
            .usernameParameter("multipartLogon")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/conv/common/logon")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/conv/")
            .failureUrl("/conv/common/logon?error=1")
            .and()

        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/conv/common/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/conv/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()

        .rememberMe()
            .key("conv_key")
            .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
            .useSecureCookie(true);
}


@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/common/**")
        .antMatchers("/favicon.ico");
}


@Bean
public RememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
    TokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("conv_key", customUserDetailsService);
    rememberMeServices.setCookieName("remember_me_cookie");
    rememberMeServices.setParameter("remember_me_checkbox");
    rememberMeServices.setTokenValiditySeconds(2678400); //1month
    return rememberMeServices;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

> my User implements UserDetails and holds the required fields. i
>   populate those and granted authorities in my CustomUserDetailsService.
>   how/when/why do i need an
>   auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()), if i check db
>   using logon/password in my service?

I think what you want is:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

The *userDetailsService* method is a shortcut for creating `DaoAuthenticationProvider` bean! You should not need both, its just two different ways to configure the same thing. The *authenticationProvider* method is used for more custom setups.

> how does spring take the submitted password, encode it and compare to
>   that stored in the db? how does it know to use the same salt as that
>   used when the p/w was created/persisted when the user was created?

If you are using BCrypt, the salt is stored in the encoded password value. The salt is the first 22 characters after the third $ (dollar) sign. The [matches](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html#matches-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.String-) method is responsible for checking the password.

> why does configureGlobal() define both auth.userDetailsService and
>   auth.authenticationProvider when authenticationProvider() also sets
>   the userDetailsService?

See above. This is likely why user details are loaded twice.

**Update:** It is weird that you get password and other details into your UserDetailsService. This should only load user based on username, something like:

```
User user = userDAO.getUserByUserLogonPassword(userLogon);
```

The returned User object should contain the encoded (stored) password, not the entered password. Spring Security does the password checking for you. You should not modify the User object in you UserDetailsService.

Comment: Hah! thx, the salt answer is very helpful. Re only UserDetailsService, yes thats the way i had it orig. I also had passwordEncoder defined exactly like your as well. With the online examples, one tends to frankenstien these things together 9 ways to sunday, hoping something works.

Comment: my problem is that my CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername() takes a colon delimited string containing much more than just username. It contains logon:password:clientId:entryUrl:etc. Yet after, when DaoAuthProvider.retrieveUser(String username..) is called, the original multiPart logon to loadUserByUsername is used and it fails auth

Comment: actually DaoAuthenticationProvider has the correct loadedUser, but then AbstractDetailsAuthenticationProvider authenticate() uses the original colon-delimited username and thats when it fails auth.

Comment: the username, p/w lookup was custom by me. I updated to only check on username. Prob is, CustomUserDetailsService work fine and the p/w is properly auto-encrypted.. but then DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser() is called and that method uses the multipartLogon originally submitted (and that contains: [userName]:[clientId]:[requestedUrl];[IPAddress]: etc. This is because i need more than just username, p/w from logon and userDetails.loadUserByUsername() only accepts a single string arg and thats auto-passed to DaoAutehnticationProvider.

Comment: @oldMan Read again. Don't mess with things like password in UserDetailsService!

Comment: going on 3 days trying to figure this out. I replaced CustomUserDetailsService with CustomDaoAutenticationProvider but the call to  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities) accepts any password and still returns a valid authentication. There is no adequate documentation that  describes the overall picture for spring security and the online examples have me coding in circles... this sucks

Comment: I still dont know why one need ret a User in UserDetailsService v. an Authentication in CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider. How can so very diff strategies both be used to satisify logon? These do not seem to be 2 diff ways to perform the same thing at all

Comment: how useful can UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities) be to authenticate when it accepts any bogus password and still returns a valid authentication?

Comment: and if one was not confused enough by spring security, here is 50 diff ways to authenticate: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Comment: @oldMan UsernamePasswordAuth‌​enticationToken does not check password, DaoAuthenticationProvider does. If you want a good overview understanding of Spring Security, I can recommend book by Peter Mularien from Packt.

Comment: Spring Security 3, Spring In Action (both editions), Spring Recipes, Introducing Spring Framework, Pro Spring, Spring Boot and both Rod Johnson books... i have them all.. read, re-read, carved up, highlighted, underlined and annotated. Yet figuring this out still takes days of frankenstein code from stackoverflow for custom UserDetailsService (didnt work), custom DaoAuthProvider (didnt work) and now custom LogonFilter. I tried DaoAuthenticationPro‌​vider, but passing any bogus password remains authenticated=true. Spring does not solve problems, it just obfuscates them with annotations :(

Answer (score 2):

Wow, ok that's a lot of questions.  I'll speak to this one:

"I have no idea how the userDetailsService, AuthenticationManagerBuilder and PasswordEncoder "

The UserDetailsService sets up the [User](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) which you can access from Spring.  If you want more user information stored in the context on the user, you need to implement your own user and set that up with your custom user details service. e.g.

```
public class CustomUser extends User implements UserDetails, CredentialsContainer {
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String emailAddress;
....
```

And then, in your custom UserDetailsService, you set the properties:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
DatabaseEntity databaseUser = this.userRepository.findByUsernameIgnoreCase(username);

customUser customUser = databaseUser.getUserDetails();
customUser.setId(databaseUser.getId());
customUser.setFirstName(databaseUser.getFirstname());
.....
```

The password encoder, is the mechanism Spring uses to compare the plain-text password to the encrypted hash in your database.   You can use the BCryptPasswordEncoder:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Aside from passing that to your auth provider, you do need to do any more.

Finally, configureGlobal is where you wire things up.  You define your user details service Spring is to use and the authentication provider.

In my case, I use a custom authentication provider to limit failed login attempts:

```
@Component("authenticationProvider")
public class LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {
```

And then I wire everything up:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationProvider")
AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider provider = (LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider)authenticationProvider;
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}
```

Comment: thx for the response Brian. Yes, i see how my post would lead one to assume i was clueless as to the basic mechanisms of userService, javaConfig, etc.

Comment: thx for the response Brian. Yes, i see how my post would lead one to assume i was clueless as to the basic mechanisms of userService, javaConfig, etc. But as evidenced by the code i included, i have all that you mention setup. I actually call a dao that get User (implements UserDetails) using BOTH userName and password. I dont see how security works when users are only loaded via username. Is there another lookup on UserDetails with the password? how/when is it encrypted (since its compares to encrypted value from db)? Does spring auto handle this? how does spring know to use the same salt?

Comment: breakpoints show a retrieved and populated User in service. I even tried manually setting the encodedPassword to the db-stored value. I get a User, but still fail spring authentication. I have to think that encoder is not being applied. I cant imagine that i manually add: new BCryptPasswordEncoder() in service to encrypt submitted p/w, as the salt would prob be diff.

Comment: in DaoAuthenticationProvider, the actual password checking happens.  See additionalAuthenticationChecks().  In my case, with my custom authentication provider, I call super:  @Override
 public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
  try {

   Authentication auth = super.authenticate(authentication);

Comment: In my case, I have not updated the class name under auth.userDetailsService(XXX) after implementing the new UserDetailService therefore I kept getting the error of `Authentication failed: password does not match stored value`

Answer (score -1):

Make ur own function name and variables in any language don't be afraid to explore make as simple as possible don't forget to use more than 10 lines for a simple outcome